# Xamarin (Visual Studio), View mapped MKMapView, not a control on view, will not show navigation bars added to view

Tags: xamarin

I created a View and mapped it to a MKMapView via code, but I cannot seem to have the Navigation Bar show up (it's the 2nd view in the stack, so it should have some ability to show the bar).

The map creates well with all functionality I want, BUT, it takes up the entire view space on the View

```
public override void LoadView()
    {

        CoreGraphics.CGRect r = new Rectangle(0, 40, (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Right, (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Bottom);
        map = new MKMapView(r);
        View = map;
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To show **Navigation Bar** , you need make sure that the **RootViewController** of the Application is an **UINavigationController** (not an **UIViewController**) .

#### in Appdeledate.cs

```
  public bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method


        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new YourViewController());
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

#### in SceneDelegate (if your app contains it)

```
  public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
    {

        Window = new UIWindow(scene as UIWindowScene);
        
        Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(new YourViewController()) ; 

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        
    }
```

And when you navigate from the first page to the map page

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(new YourMapController(),true);
```

[image]